# Custom Entity login error Symfony2.7

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm using Symfony 2.7 and I'm having trouble logging users. I use Custom Entity and I have created a custom entity "Operator" with proper variables and methods. I use two login methods in security file. One is `in_memory` and I use it for admin login which works correctly and the other one is `user_db`. I use bcrypt algorithm to encrypt the passwords. When I try to log in a user, it displays "Invalid credentials" message. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Application\AdminBundle\Entity\Operator:
            algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [ in_memory, user_db ]

user_db:
            entity:
                class: ApplicationAdminBundle:Operator
                property: username
```

SecurityController.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
* @Route("/login", name="login")
*/
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    return $this->render('ApplicationAdminBundle:security:login.html.twig',
        array(
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );
}

/**
* @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
*/
public function loginCheckAction()
{
}

}
```

"Operator" Entity and setPassword(), getPassword() methods

```
public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = password_hash ($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

All I had done wrong was the database table because the I had set the password field as `varchar(25)` and the hashed password could not be fully inserted. I changed it to `varchar(255)` and everything is ok now. Every user can now login.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should not use `password_hash` you have to use symfony's encoder who knows how to handle the encryption of the password. 
Try to implement something like this in your code ( in register controller usually ) : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#dynamically-encoding-a-password

Visit this page http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html   to fully understand how symfony2 security works.

Comment: All I had done wrong was the database table because the I had set the password field as "varchar(25)" and the hashed password could not be fully inserted. I changed it to "varchar(255)" and everything is ok now. Every user can now login.